# How to dynamically pass argument to useContractRead()?

Tags: wagmi

I am trying to pass an argument to the hook based on the user input.

The flow will be

=> user types the number in the input field

=> value stored in the state

=> state value passed as an argument to the hook

Here is a sample code

```js
const RandomComponent = ()=>{
  const [uncliamedAmountValue, setUnclaimedAmountValue] = useState()
  const  [{data, error}, contractInstane]  = useContractRead({
    address: '0xE6b2263c0F2Fc2D078fED69A329E0eF5fBD52b74',
    abi: getunclaimedamount,
    functionName: 'getUnclaimedAmount',
  })

  const handleClick = () => {
   console.log("button clicked");
   contractInstane({
    args: [ethers.BigNumber.from(uncliamedAmountValue)],
   })
  }

  return(
  <div>
    <input type="number" onChange((e)=> setUnclaimedAmountValue(e.target.value)) value={uncliamedAmountValue} />
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Get data</button>
  </div>
  )
}
```

The above code doesn't work. I tried "contractInstane" because I saw a similar approach to pass arguments to the `useContractwrite` but in this case, it doesn't work

Documentation: https://wagmi.sh/react/hooks/useContractRead

Answer (score 0):

Try to doing this way:

```
const RandomComponent = ()=>{
  const [uncliamedAmountValue, setUnclaimedAmountValue] = useState()
   // update your input:
  const updateInput = event => {
    setUnclaimedAmountValue(event.target.value)
  }

  const  [{data, error}, contractInstane]  = useContractRead({
    address: '0xE6b2263c0F2Fc2D078fED69A329E0eF5fBD52b74',
    abi: getunclaimedamount,
    functionName: 'getUnclaimedAmount',
  })

  const handleClick = () => {
   console.log("button clicked");
   contractInstane({
    args: [ethers.BigNumber.from(uncliamedAmountValue)],
   })
  }

  return(
  <div>
    <input type="number" onChange={updateInput} value={''} />
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Get data</button>
  </div>
  )
}
```

In this way when you change your input, your `uncliamedAmountValue` updated by `updateInput` function, then you can use `uncliamedAmountValue` amount in your function, if it doesn't work , lets check if you get the input amount correctly or not, with a log.

Comment: this doesn't work